# Остановка потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Cуществует поток, который один раз в секунду выводит текущее время.

Каким образом можно прервать его выполнение путем ввода с клавиатуры?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Task3 extends Thread {

    public void run(){
        while (true){
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Task3().start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Разделите задачу на части:

1. Получение команды от пользователя с клавиатуры.
2. Передача сообщения бегущему потоку.
3. Внутри потока: окончание работы потока.

Подумайте, как решать каждую из них. Подумайте, как скомбинировать это в решение вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

В треде, выводящем на экран, вставить условие проверки на команду остановки (не обязательно, так как `sleep()` проверяет это условие сам, внутри), а в `main` давать команду остановки. Причем в вашем коде прекращение потока не произойдет никогда, потому что метод `interrupt()`, прерывающий поток, выбросит `InterruptedException`, чтобы остановить поток, но у вас произойдет перехват этого исключения внутри цикла, а затем продолжится цикл и вывод дат на экран. Надо или `try` вынести за пределы цикла, как это сделал я в примере кода, или внутри `catch` добавить `break` для прекращения цикла, выхода из метода `run()` и, как следствие, остановки треда.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Task3 extends Thread {

public void run(){
    try {
        while (!isInterrupted()){
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Thread task = new ComplexNumber();
    task.start();
    BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    consoleReader.readLine();
    task.interrupt();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

System.in - это InputStream и он не равен null. Из него нужно читать что-то. В вашем же случае тред должен сразу прекратить работу. Неплохо бы было сначала посмотреть в документацию, а потом уже задавать вопрос, если бы он возник.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал решить вопрос на скорую руку.
Один поток (stream2) исполнения выводит время на консоль. 
Второй (stream2) слушает клавиатуру и как только считывает клавишу с keycode = 10 (Enter) завершает выполнение программы. 
Листинг:

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new KeyReader();
        (new Thread(r, "stream1")).start();

        Runnable t = new Timer();
        (new Thread(t, "stream2")).start();
    }}

class KeyReader implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

        int i;
        try {
            i = System.in.read();
            for (i = 0; i == 10;) {
                i = System.in.read();
            }
            System.out.println("Выполнение остановлено пользователем");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка ввода данных");
        }
    }}
class Timer implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }}
```

Так же можно добавить потокам приоритеты, и осуществлять сначала, перед System.exit() завершение потока, исполняющего вывод времени, но т.к. Thread.stop()  объявлен depricated - я его использовать не стал.

Comment: @Qassarb, позвольте с Вашим решением не согласиться.

Вы прервали не thread Timer, а завершили всю программу (все 3 thread-а).